# Webpack not starting script

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I am new to Webpack and Angular and Typescript.  Below is my code in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
@Styles.Render("~/ClientApp/Dist/Dev/vendor.css");
</head>
<body >
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
          @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</div>

    <script src="~/ClientApp/Dist/Dev/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ClientApp/Dist/Dev/main.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this from VS2010, all I get is the _LoginPartial page loaded.

Why won't these scripts run?

```
<script src="~/ClientApp/Dist/Dev/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="~/ClientApp/Dist/Dev/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: The main.js script has a reference to the app.module.ts which has the @NgModule declaration pointing to a component home.component.ts which utilizes the "templateUrl" command to load an html page which simply has <h1>Hello World</h1>.  I did not include these things because I want to keep it simple.  It appears to me that angular.js is not getting loaded by webpack...?

Comment: Looks like vendor.js is not loading and therefore main.js is not loading and rendering the app.module.  So I do not get my "Hello World" on the web page.  Here is the error that I see which is causing vendor.js not to load:  The source map 'toPromise.js.map' for file \vendor.js' could not be read from the specified location due to error 'Exception of type 'TypeScriptSourceMapReader.SourceMapReadFailedException' was thrown.'.The program '[4156] chrome.exe: WebKit' has exited with code -1

Comment: This is very frustrating: debugging in IE I can set a  breakpoint in main.js at this line "module.exports = vendor;"  However when it gets to vendor.js it throws an error in this function which has been discussed as a bug in IE:  function combine(options) {
    return ((Object)).assign.apply(((Object)), [{}].concat(options));
}.  Debugging in Chrome, nothing happens but I see in Output the TypeScriptSourceMapReader error as detailed in the above comment...  Can anyone help???